# Heirs of Godric Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter

If Harry is not the heir of Godric Gryffindor as per this question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/was-harry-potter-literally-descended-from-godric-gryffindor), then who is in among all the other characters?

Comment: Why do any of them *have* to be an Heir of Gryffindor? It's possible his line died out entirely.

Comment: It is popularly believed that Harry was the heir, as Voldermort was the heir of Slytherin.

Comment: The fact that it is a popular belief doesn't mean that anyone is (or isn't)

Comment: @phantom42 The link to the other answer says that Harry is not a heir

Comment: Right, but to my recollection, there is nothing in the books saying that there is an heir of Gryffindor out there. So, as @AnthonyGrist was trying to point out, the fact that Harry is not the heir does not mean that anyone else is either. To be clear, I don't think either of us think this is a *bad* question, just that your justification is flawed.

Comment: @phantom42 You are free to change the justification, all I want to know from the experts of HP here, is there an heir of Gordic Gryffindor mentioned somewhere. If the answer is NO, I am ok with it. But I was surprised to the negative votes.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you down voted me because I asked whether Dumbeldore might be the heir, look here at this answer before you throw your weight around http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19175/is-dumbledore-a-gryffindor?rq=1

Comment: What does Dumbledore being sorted into the Gryffindor house have to do with anything?

Answer (score 4):

Per [Was Harry Potter literally descended from Godric Gryffindor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/was-harry-potter-literally-descended-from-godric-gryffindor) -- as you note in this question -- Harry himself is not a direct descendant from Gryffindor, despite popular fan belief.

There is no mention of Godric Gryffindor's family or heirs in any of the seven Potter books. I personally know of no interview, online or otherwise, with J.K. Rowling where any of Gryffindor's heirs are discussed. Pottermore has new canon material available through *Goblet of Fire*, but I'm still reading that section of the site, so I don't know if Gryffindor's line is discussed at that point in Pottermore. I don't recall Gryffindor being discussed on Pottermore in the sections of Pottermore that review books 1-3. **At this time, no relatives, family, or true heir(s) of Godric Gryffindor are known.**

As always, anybody is free to correct me if there's some obscure reference out there!

Comment: being a cousin 5 times removed is still technically related

Comment: @severa - Yes, that's true. Do you have a source that  indicates Harry is Godric Gryffindor's cousin five times removed? If so, please share! :)

Comment: no source, just a comment

Comment: @Slytherincess I am surprised because we already have mentions about the heirs of Salazar Slytherin and Rowena Ravenclaw

Comment: Well, if Griffindor was a pureblood or even a half-blood (and we can assume he was, as he was born in a wizarding hamlet that would later be named after him, and founded the most famous school of wizardry in the world) then EVERY single half-blood wizard (in the UK, at least) would be related to him - including Harry.

Answer (score -7):

New news: an heir to Gryffindor has surfaced as a McLaggen ancestor who is going to be a part of a new film! She is a descendant of Gryffindor and shares the name of Cormac McLaggen which leads us to believe that Cormac is even a great descendant of Godric Gryffindor himself.

Comment: Where did you find this news?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems quite unexpected, would it be possible to provide evidence to support these claims?

Comment: Hi, Nick. This appears to be from a trailer to a fanfilm, not something we would generally consider to be canon.

Comment: Yes, it's the trailer for a fan film. Here's a link to an article about it, which also has 2 trailers for it, if anyone wants to see what this is about. https://www.buzzfeed.com/andreborges/voldemort-origins-of-the-heir?bfsource=bbf_enus&utm_term=.bg8vE1zdGN#.vr1P8yloBE