# Does any of the Hogwarts' staff have a family?

Tags: harry-potter

In the seven *Harry Potter* books, the reader meets about two dozen of Hogwarts' teachers, but I don't remember any of them having either a spouse or children.

They are all grown adults, often even elderly, so this seems a bit surprising. After all, in the Muggle world, high-school teachers often happen to have a family life beside their job.

What have I found so far:

- Remus Lupin marries Nymphadora Tonks and fathers Teddy. However, this happens several years after his one-year appointment as DADA teacher in Hogwarts.
- Hagrid develops a romance with Madame Maxime in GoF, but it is unclear how far it goes, and I can find no mention of her after their trip to Europe.
- Snape has been madly in love with Lily Potter all his life, but she has never reciprocated and we can reasonably infer that he never had any bond with anyone else.
- We [know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191215/do-any-of-the-hogwarts-founders-have-living-descendants) that at least three of the four Hogwarts founders (Slytherin, Hufflepuff and Ravenclaw) had children, but I am more interested in 20th century teachers.
- Among the ghosts, the Bloody Baron and the Grey Lady have, hum, a complicated history.

**Is any teacher of Hogwarts known to be married or to have a child?** If no, has any justification for this been advanced?

Any information about the non-teaching staff (Pomfrey, Filch, Pince...) or the former headmasters is also welcomed.

Comment: Does the epilogue count? Neville becomes a professor and married Hannah Abbot.

Comment: A subtle, and perhaps accidental, feature of the story is how few children wizards have. Harry, Nevile, James, Lucius, Luna, Tom, Remus, Cedric, Scorpius and many others are only children. It's notable when there are two children in a Wizarding family that make it to adulthood (Rose/Hugo, Padma/Parvati, Dumbledore/Dumbledore, Sirius/Regulus). This causes even pure blond families to be regular tainted and even the purest to not 'actually' be pure; a lot of intermarrying has to occur to keep the charade going.

Comment: @Lan What about the Weasley's with... 5? children?

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate since it seems to be the same as the other one. If you’re looking for something else you can [edit] to clarify the differences.

Comment: @FreeMan And Malfoy points out it as abnormal. In the 1996 Census in Canada, families with 4+ children were 13+% of the population. One child families were 21% (not filtering out the families who would later have another child). In other words, if the Wizarding world has normal family sizes in the 1990s, 4+ children should be as common as 1 children families. (There was the whole 'wizarding war' bit but that tends to make the survivors breed more; families like the Longbottoms and Potters being 'non survivors' and unable to have more children.)

Answer (score 1):

## Professor Minerva McGonagall

Minerva had a marriage, albeit a short one, to Elphinstone Urquart who worked with her at the Ministry although their marriage only occurred years later when she was teaching at Hogwarts.

> #### Marriage
>
> Through all her early years at Hogwarts, Minerva McGonagall remained on terms of friendship with her old boss at the Ministry, Elphinstone Urquart. He came to visit her while on holiday to Scotland, and to her great surprise and embarrassment, proposed marriage in Madam Puddifoot’s teashop. Still in love with Dougal McGregor, Minerva turned him down.
>
> Elphinstone, however, had never ceased to love her, nor to propose every now and then, even though she continued to refuse him. The death of Dougal McGregor, however, although traumatic, seemed to free Minerva. Shortly after Voldemort’s first defeat, Elphinstone, now white-haired, proposed again during a summertime stroll around the lake in the Hogwarts grounds. This time Minerva accepted. Elphinstone, now retired, was beside himself with joy, and purchased a small cottage in Hogsmeade for the pair of them, whence Minerva could travel easily to work every day.
>
> Known to successive generations of students as ‘Professor McGonagall’, Minerva – always something of a feminist – announced that she would be keeping her own name upon marriage. Traditionalists sniffed – why was Minerva refusing to accept a pure-blood name, and keeping that of her Muggle father?
>
> The marriage (cut tragically short, though it was destined to be) was a very happy one. Though they had no children of their own, Minerva’s nieces and nephews (children of her brothers Malcolm and Robert) were frequent visitors to their home. This was a period of great fulfillment for Minerva.
>
> The accidental death of Elphinstone from a Venomous Tentacula bite, three years into their marriage, was an enormous sorrow to all who knew the couple. Minerva could not bear to remain alone in their cottage, but packed her things after Elphinstone’s funeral and returned to her sparse stone-floored bedroom in Hogwarts Castle, accessible through a concealed door in the wall of her first-floor study. Always a very brave and private person, she poured all her energies into her work, and few people – excepting perhaps Albus Dumbledore – ever realised how much she suffered.
>
> <sub>[Pottermore, Professor McGonagall By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall)</sub>

For more context on Dougal read the article and see the part titled "Early Heartbreak".